# Standard installer image library

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a standard installer image library for installer UI? I noticed that there are common icons used in different installers but I cannot find a resource library released by wix is microsoft which has them.

Some examples of the images:
[http://fossies.org/linux/misc/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src.tar.gz/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src/wix/resources/setup_type_typical.ico](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src.tar.gz/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src/wix/resources/setup_type_complete.ico)
http://fossies.org/linux/misc/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src.tar.gz/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src/wix/resources/setup_type_custom.ico
http://fossies.org/linux/misc/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src.tar.gz/mysql-connector-odbc-5.2.6-src/wix/resources/setup_type_complete.ico

Answer (score 1):

Each tool comes with it's own set.  There is no industry standard.  Also beware of copyright / licensing issues if you just go grabbing them off the web.

Comment: That makes sense. Could you provide examples of such tools? I'd want to add some consistency to my installers and haven't found any such resource.